# Multiple axis excel 2010 chart

Tags: excel-charts

I´d like to create excel chart with multiple axis x using dynamic - offset defined range.

I have columns A, B, C - for multiple axis. If I define this as a range e.g `A2:C50` then the items (values) in the rows are ordered to multiple axis (horizontal categories - in chart data definition). In column D i have trend values - Y axis.

But I would need to define this range dynamicaly using offset. I created named range `MultipleAxis` defined as `=OFFSET($A$2:$C$50;0;0;COUNT($D$2:$D$50);1)`. I used this range in definition of horizontal categories but I see on the X axis only values from column A and no multiple axis option is set.

Is it possible to define multiple axis in Excel 2010 chart using dynamic defined range by offset?

Thank You very much for help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The mistake what I made was in the definition of offset function. The correct using offset function must be this: =OFFSET($A$2;0;0;COUNT($D$2:$D$50);3).